# Float and Int Both 4 Bytes? How Come?

Tags: floating-point, int

Int is 4 bytes with a range of +- 2^31
Float is 4 bytes with a range of +- 1.2E(+- 38)

Float encompasses so many more points on the Real Line and yet is equal to the size of int. Is the Sign-Exponent-Fraction representation of float so awesome (or the 2's complement of Int so pathetic) that this size disparity arises? Am I missing something?

I just find it highly surprising that something which represents (virtually) the entire real line is of the same size as that of which represents the Integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do float and int have such different maximum values even though they're the same number of bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158476/why-do-float-and-int-have-such-different-maximum-values-even-though-theyre-the)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In C, an `int` and `float` each take up 4 bytes, or 32 bits, in memory.  The difference between `int` and `float` is not the number of bits they take up in memory, but rather in the way the ALU (Arithmetic Logic Unit) treats each number.  An `int` is treated as the integer represented by its bits using [two's complement notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  A `float`, on the other hand, is encoded (typically in [IEEE 754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_standard:_binary32)) to represent a number in exponential form (e.g. 2.9979245x10<sup>8</sup> is a number in exponential form with base 2.9979245 and exponent 8).  The *number of significant digits* in the decimal representation of a floating point number is always about the same: 6-9 digits for 32-bit float and 15-17 digits for a 64-bit float (or `double`).  For example, the value 4.2949673x10<sup>9</sup> is what I get as the decimal representation of the closest 32-bit float to the number 2<sup>32</sup> , and it has 8 significant digits.

It can be a common misconception that a floating point number somehow represents *more information* than a fixed-point number, which is not true.  While a 32-bit `float` can represent numbers of greater magnitude than a 32-bit `int`, it cannot represent all of them with as much precision.  In total, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64199262/1131073) derives that a 32-bit `float` can represent around 4,278,190,081 unique numbers.  This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24179424/1131073) contains a nice plot showing how these 32-bit `float`s are distributed on the real line.

While an `int` may not be able to represent numbers with as large of a magnitude as a `float`, it represents each number in its valid range (-2<sup>32</sup> to 2<sup>32</sup>-1) with the same precision.  The largest number it can represent is 2,147,483,647 and has 10 significant digits.  And in total, it can represent 2<sup>32</sup>=4,294,967,296 unique numbers, which is more than for the 32-bit `float`!

Comment: Thanks. That was really helpful. The IEEE 754 standard throws some light on the nature of approximation of even natural numbers.

Answer (score 32):

> I just find it highly surprising that something which represents (virtually) the entire real line is of the same size as that of which represents the Integers.

Perhaps this will become less surprising once you realize that there are lots of integers that a 32-bit `int` can represent exactly, and a 32-bit `float` can't.

A `float` can represent fewer **distinct** numbers than an `int`, but they're spread over a wider range.

It is also worth noting that the spacing between consecutive `floats` becomes wider as one moves away from zero, whereas it remains constant for consecutive `ints`.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thank You !

Answer (score 2):

I believe the important point here is that int is exact while float may be rounded.  A portion of the data in a float describes the location of the decimal, while another portion determines the value.  So while you may be able to show 1.2E38, only the first several digits may be correct and the rest may be filled with 0's.

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

"with seven decimal digits could in addition represent 1.234567, 123456.7, 0.00001234567, 1234567000000000, and so on"

It depends on how the particular system implements floats.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should learn [how floating point numbers are represented in a computer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) It is very different from the way integers are represented.

Also it is worth noting that an int is not always 4 byte long, it depends on the system.

Comment: Float is not always 4 bytes, too. Some 8-bit microcontroller compilers have an option to use 24-bit float.

Answer (score 0):

Both types represent the same amount of points on the real line - they are just spaced differently. The difference between the highest and the second-highest float is ca. 256!

Comment: Actually float represents fewer points on the real line since float has a lot of NaN-values: 2^24 - 2 = 16'777'214 of them to be exact (the -2 is for +/-infinity) of which 2^23 = 8'388'608 are so called "quiet NaNs" (all considered to be equivalent* and thus they waste a lot of values). The rest is "signaling NaNs" and although distinct as far as the IEEE-754 standard is concerned they rarely have real use, so the extra information they carry ("payload") is ignored by most systems. Float also has two different zeros (+/-0 are distinct). Summary: float has 16'777'217 fewer real values than int.

Answer (score 0):

Standard for floating point as per standards requires a base=2 instead of base=10 and 24 digits (precision). Since it is not base 10, the base 2 format is capable of representing only a definite set of real numbers (which is the inherent reason of error in representing real numbers). It also means, as you though earlier, that float is not representing many more numbers as compared to int.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the length of a certain data type differs on platforms. Yet let us say now `float` and `int` are same, 4 bytes.

4 Bytes equal 32 bits, and in binary, the range is

> 00000000000000000000000000000000

to

> 11111111111111111111111111111111

At this point, we should recall **geometric sequence**, the sum above equals

> 2^32 + 2^31 + ... + 2^1 + 2^0 = 2147483648

Notice, C redfines the range from math to language, as `unsigned` or `signed` via shift.

That is to say it can also define `float`.

> SEEEEEEEEMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
>
> S = sign (1 bit)
>
> E = exponent (8 bits)
>
> M = mantissa (23 bits)

The value calculation follows **IEEE-754**, which is not easy, but we can try at [754 converter](https://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_float.html) :)

Now, the range, (see the exponent trick? It means E-127, minus!)

> 0 00000001 00000000000000000000000

to

> 0 11111110 11111111111111111111111

From math,

> 2^-126 * 1.00000000000000000000000  = 1.1754943508222875 × 10^-38

to

> 2^(128) * 1.11111111111111111111111 = 3.7809151880104275 x 10^38

Notice there is a hidden 1 for mantissa, otherwise you always get 0 :<

At last machines are built for saving life at the very begining, so before we choose the data type, we better checkout the range, from the header files, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Range of signed char %d to %d\n", SCHAR_MIN, SCHAR_MAX);
    printf("Range of unsigned char 0 to %d\n\n", UCHAR_MAX);

    printf("Range of signed short int %d to %d\n", SHRT_MIN, SHRT_MAX);
    printf("Range of unsigned short int 0 to %d\n\n", USHRT_MAX);

    printf("Range of signed int %d to %d\n", INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("Range of unsigned int 0 to %lu\n\n", UINT_MAX);

    printf("Range of signed long int %ld to %ld\n", LONG_MIN, LONG_MAX);
    printf("Range of unsigned long int 0 to %lu\n\n", ULONG_MAX);

    // In some compilers LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX
    printf("Range of signed long long int %lld to %lld\n", LLONG_MIN, LLONG_MAX); 
    // In some compilers ULLONG_MAX
    printf("Range of unsigned long long int 0 to %llu\n\n", ULLONG_MAX); 

    printf("Range of float %e to %e\n", FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX);
    printf("Range of double %e to %e\n", DBL_MIN, DBL_MAX);
    printf("Range of long double %e to %e\n", LDBL_MIN, LDBL_MAX);

    return 0;
}
```