# Why do float and int have such different maximum values even though they're the same number of bits?

Tags: c#, java, c++, floating-point, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what the difference between the float and integer data type when the size is same in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806944/what-the-difference-between-the-float-and-integer-data-type-when-the-size-is-sam)

As you probably know, both of these types are 32-bits.`int` can hold only integer numbers, whereas `float` also supports [floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) numbers (as the type names suggest).

How is it possible then that the max value of `int` is 2<sup>31</sup>, and the max value of  `float` is 3.4*10<sup>38</sup>, while both of them are 32 bits?

I think that `int`'s max value capacity should be higher than the float because it doesn't save memory for the floating number and accepts only integer numbers. I'll be glad for an explanation in that case.

Comment: Where are you getting the max floating point value of 3.4 * 10 ^ 38 from?

Comment: The precision of the float for large numbers is much lower than an int.

Comment: Hmm... You say "floating numbers" as if it's obvious to you what that means, but is it?

Comment: Obligatory link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Imagine you have an `int` value which represents a price in cents and another `int` value which represents a price in dollars. The question is; how can the amount in dollars be more than the amount in cents? If you can answer that question, you have answered your own. ;)

Comment: How do you know an `int` is represented using 32-bits? This might be true for C# and Java, but not for C++.

Comment: A `float` and an `int` are *not* **necesarrily** exactly 32 bits.  The Standard doesn't define the sizes absolutely -- only in terms relative to other types.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your intuition quite rightly tells you that there can be no more **information content** in one than the other, because they both have 32 bits. But that doesn't mean we can't use those bits to **represent** different values.

Suppose I invent two new datatypes, `uint4` and `foo4`. `uint4` uses 4 bits to represent an integer, in the standard binary representation, so we have

```
bits   value
0000       0
0001       1
0010       2
...
1111      15
```

But `foo4` uses 4 bits to represent these values:

```
bits   value
0000       0
0001      42
0010     -97
0011       1
...
1110      pi
1111       e
```

Now `foo4` has a  much **wider** range of values than `uint4`, despite having the same number of bits! How? Because there are some `uint4` values that **can't** be represented by `foo4`, so those 'slots' in the bit mapping are available for other values.

---

It is the same for `int` and `float` - they can both store values from a set of 2<sup>32</sup> values, just *different* sets of 2<sup>32</sup> values.

Comment: Very interesting, easy to understand(though not technical) explanation.  I like it.

Comment: Great explanation on the bit structure of floats: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&list=PL9D558D49CA734A02&v=jTSvthW34GU#t=1984s

Answer (score 15):

A float might store a higher number value, but it will not be precise even on digits before the decimal dot.
Consider the following example:

```
float a = 123456789012345678901234567890f; //30 digits
Console.WriteLine(a);  // 1.234568E+29
```

Notice that barely any precision is kept.

An integer on the other hand will always precisely store any number within its range of values.

For the sake of comparison, let's look at a double precision floating point number:

```
double a = 123456789012345678901234567890d; //30 digits
Console.WriteLine(a); // 1.23456789012346E+29
```

Notice that roughly twice as much significant digits are preserved.

Comment: You are demonstrating writing to console here. Does that really tell us anything about precision?

Comment: Maybe this "console print" example makes it more clear (java code):
System.out.println(16828700f == 16828700f + 1f); // => true

Answer (score 7):

These are based on IEEE754 floating point specification, that is why it is possible. Please read this [documentation](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html). It is not just about how many bits.

Answer (score 4):

The hint is in the "floating" part of "floating point". What you say basically assumes fixed point. A floating point number does not "reserve space" for the digits after the decimal point - it has a limited number of digits (23 binary) and remembers what power of two to multiply it by.