# C++ floating point type that doesn't use scientific notation to represent very small values?

Tags: c++

I'm writing an algorithm that deals with [Logit-normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution) transformations which have the characteristic that, with high enough sigmas/means, the values can be "compressed" towards the edges at 0 and 1 very tightly. I'm encountering the problem where values that should be different collide because the C++ double can't represent sufficient digits. For example, I'm applying the sigmoid/logistic function to two high enough but different values, the outcome is identical when it shouldn't be if doubles could hold higher precision.

I can deal with that by aggregating samples that collide onto the same value. But the issue is that around 1, the collision happens, because numbers are represented like this: 0.999999999953 for example. But around 0 it doesn't happen, because C++ starts to represent values in scientific notation, like so: 0.12949384e-300. The latter can achieve much higher precision therefore no collision happens here. But I would need symmetrical behavior for both the values around 0 and 1 to make sure the result is computed the same way on both sides.

Is there such a type in C++ that does not automatically switch to scientific notations when representing extremely small values? So I could achieve the same behavior around 0 that I get around 1?

Comment: Scientific notation is a display feature , not an internal representation. Look up "IEEE854" for explanation of how most C++ implementations store floating point numbers.  If you need higher precision arithmetic than `long double` offers on your system, you will need to find some math library offering such a feature.

Comment: Better yet, IEEE754, since that is the standard in use.

Comment: What is a collision?

Comment: [boost multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) may be useful, you can make 128 bit fast floats for higher precision.

Comment: You can get the same precision at 0 and 1 simply by using a fixed-point format. UQ0.64 would give you 64-bits of precision throughout the interval from 0 to 1, excluding 1, which is more than the format commonly used for `double` gives. (UQ0.64 means a number x is encoded as the integer x•2^64, so .375 = .25 + .125 would be encoded as 2^62+2^61.) For more precision near 0 and 1, you could encode the numbers with bit indicating endpoint and a distance from that endpoint. For example, the floating-point number x could represent 0+x if its sign bit is zero and 1−x if its sign bit is one.

Comment: For even more precision, you could change that to 0+x/2^1024 and 1−x/2^1024, to use nearly the full exponent range of the IEEE-754 binary64 format. For further answers, you should specify the needs further and clearly. Do you need to be able to encode 0 and 1 exactly, or just numbers near them? How much precision do you need near 0 and 1? How much near the midpoint? Do you just need to store and retrieve numbers? Or do you also need to convert them to and from decimal representations or other representations? Do you need to do arithmetic with them?

Comment: If so, what arithmetic? Do you need to be able to add two of these numbers? Do you need to multiply two of these numbers? Do you need to multiply one of these numbers by small integers or other ordinarily represented numbers?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the internal representation and not the display? Unhelpfully by default output streams show fewer places around 1.0 than around 0.0. Please post a runnable code example of your problem. Sure you can look for higher precision arithmetic options but they are often 'extend and pretend' the underlying precision of the arithmetic isn't the real issue with the code.

Comment: Try the code below and notice that displays many more places of precision that were there all along. https://ideone.com/LcsHtq

    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <limits>

    int main() {
     double eps{std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()};
     double one_minus_eps{1.0-eps};
     std::cout << eps << '\n';
     std::cout << one_minus_eps << '\n';
     std::cout << std::scientific << std::setprecision(20) << one_minus_eps << '\n'; 
         return 0;
    }

Comment: @AhmedAEK I looked into that already but the code must be very performant so using such compound types is not an option

Comment: Please post some relevant code. 64-bits is enough for many places of accuracy and you would need something like 900 bit floating point to represent 1.0-1.0E-300 and have as much accuracy around 1.0 as you currently get around 0,0. But without some code for us to help with this is a nearly unanswerable question.

Comment: if you really want both fast code and high precision, and you have a certain range of numbers you might want to look into using fixed point numbers instead of floating point, as while `double` has only 14 digits of dynamic range, you can get 21 digits from `long` and it's much faster, but it's too tricky to implement and this should not be used in any production code (usually done in custom hardware, like FPGAs)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I think that sounds like the best approach for my problem. Representing the range from 0 to 1 by a 64bit integer will ensure consistent behavior on both ends.

Comment: @M.M This is what I assumed but I got very confused by seeing the Visual Studio compiler display very low doubles with exponents as low as ~e^-300 while showing values just below one without the exponent and consequently much less precision. I also checked the doubles that were transformed onto exactly 1.000... for equality to 1 and it was always true, so it was not just a display inaccuracy of the debugger. I admit I don't know much about how floating point numbers are stored internally. I should look into that.
The fact that DBL_MIN and DBL_EPSILON are not the same confused me even more

Comment: @artificial_lunacy The thing is internally floating point is (binary) scientific notation amounting to ±m*2^e at all scales. That's pretty much what floating-point means. The number of digits are fixed but the point shifts (floats) rather than fixed precision.

Comment: I found some other links that describe better what I have observed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047270/understanding-floating-point-precision
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number

Comment: Rather than take the log(x/(1-x)) take the log of the intermediaries:  log(x)-log(1-x) This will get much more dynamic range. There are also math simplifications if your intermediates are close to 0 or 1 that you should use to calculate the logs.

Comment: scientific notation when printing the value has nothing to do with floating-point types, just a display issue. There are things in `<iomanip>` like `std::setprecision` and various `printf` flags like `%e`, `%g`, %f`... to deal with this. Anyway all floating-point types are technically scientific notation under the hood. And the question is still very vague. How much precision do you need? How small and how big are the values? How much performance do you require? ... Outside C++ there are formats like posits or log-scale format that can be used more efficiently for very large/small values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type `long double`. It has typically on x86 [80 bits precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) which is the original precision of the 8087 coprocessor.

Note that Microsoft dropped support for it long ago.

GCC supports the type `__float128` that implements [IEEE754 quadruple precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format). This is nice since if you use Linux its probably already there.

Boost multiprecision offers a 128 bit cross platform facade for the above. However you would typically bring the boost library dependency into your application, which can be daunting in certain scenarios. UPDATE: boost multiprecision's float128 does not compile on MSVC/Windows.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include "boost/format.hpp"
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

template< typename T >
[[gnu::noinline]] T calc(T a,T b,T c) {
    return T(1) - (T(1)/a + T(1)/b + T(1)/c );
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "     Epsilon        Error"<< std::endl;
    boost::format fmt( "%12.6g %12.6g" );
    std::cout << fmt % std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon() % calc<double>(3,2,6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fmt % std::numeric_limits<long double>::epsilon() % calc<long double>(3,2,6) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fmt % double(std::numeric_limits<__float128>::epsilon()) % double(calc<__float128>(3,2,6)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << fmt % std::numeric_limits<mp::float128>::epsilon() % calc<mp::float128>(3,2,6) << std::endl;
}
```

Results in

```
Program stdout
     Epsilon        Error
 2.22045e-16  1.11022e-16
  1.0842e-19            0
           0  9.62965e-35
 1.92593e-34  9.62965e-35
```

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/nPn1TvTeb)

However note there is a huge performance penalty for the 128 bit precision. I wrote a benchmark using the above formula and the results are:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                   Time             CPU   Iterations
-------------------------------------------------------------
Calc<double>           375575 ns       375514 ns         1864
Calc<long double>      531313 ns       531228 ns         1318
Calc<__float128>     12943995 ns     12941473 ns           54
Calc<mp::float128>   13074108 ns     13071816 ns           54
```

Comment: I am restricted to MSVC where 64bit is the most you get for floating point numbers sadly

Comment: If you are doing sums, try to use Kahan sum instead which keeps precision. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm

Comment: 'Note that Microsoft dropped support for it long ago:' In fact I believe they never really had it. They had the keywords for it, but never the 80 bits. I looked into this in 1995. I had to switch to an IBM compiler.

Comment: @user207421 that's not true. [16-bit MSVC supports 80-bit long double](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9751/did-any-compiler-fully-use-intel-x87-80-bit-floating-point/9760#comment31473_9759). It was only dropped since 32-bit MSVC for the better SSE float which is more consistent and reproducible

Comment: @phuclv Thank you, I was working with 32-bit code at the time. IBM C/C++ supported 80-bit floats properly, Microsoft did not.