# Generating random integer and real numbers in a given range

Tags: random, chapel

According the man page of [getNext](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/modules/standard/Random/PCGRandom.html#PCGRandom.PCGRandomStream.getNext) in the [PCGRandom](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/modules/standard/Random/PCGRandom.html#pcgrandom) module, we can generate random numbers in a given range, for example:

```
use Random;

var rng1 = new owned RandomStream( eltType= real, seed= 100 );
var rng2 = new owned RandomStream( eltType= int,  seed= 100 );

for i in 1..5 do
    writeln( rng1.getNext( min= 3.0, max= 5.0 ) );

writeln();
for i in 1..5 do
    writeln( rng2.getNext( min= 20, max= 80 ) );
```

which gives (with chpl-1.20.0):

```
4.50371
4.85573
4.2246
4.84289
3.63607

36
57
79
39
57
```

Here, I noticed that the man page gives the following notes for both the integer and real-number cases:

> For integers, this class uses a strategy for generating a value in a particular range that has not been subject to rigorous study and *may have statistical problems*.
>
> For real numbers, this class generates a random value in [max, min] by computing a random value in [0,1] and scaling and shifting that value. Note that *not all possible floating point values in the interval [min, max] can be constructed in this way*.

(where I used italics for emphasis). For real numbers, is this related to the so-called "density of floating-point number", e.g. asked in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006510/density-of-floating-point-number-magnitude-of-the-number))? Also, for integers, is there some case that we need to be careful even for "typical" use?
(here, "typical" means, e.g., a generation of 10**8 random integers distributed approximately flat in a given range.)

FYI, my "use case" is not something like rigorous quality tests for random numbers, but just typical Monte Carlo calculations (e.g., selecting random sites on a cubic lattice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notes in the manual page are indicating a difference from the other PCG random number methods that have been studied (by the author of the PCG algorithm at the very least).

The issue with floating-point numbers is indeed related to floating-point number density. See http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-c-basic.html#generating-doubles from the PCG author. It is a potential problem even when generating random numbers in [0.0, 1.0]. This paragraph from the documentation describes the issue:

> When generating a real, imaginary, or complex number, this
>   implementation uses the strategy of generating a 64-bit unsigned
>   integer and then multiplying it by 2.0**-64 in order to convert it to
>   a floating point number. While this does construct a uniform
>   distribution on rounded floating point values, it leaves out many
>   possible real values (for example, 2**-128). We believe that this
>   strategy has reasonable statistical properties. One side effect of
>   this strategy is that the real number 1.0 can be generated because of
>   rounding. The real number 0.0 can be generated because PCG can produce
>   the value 0 as a random integer.

Note that a 64-bit real can store numbers as small as `2.0**-1024` but it is quite impossible to get such a number by dividing a positive integer by `2**64`. (Here and in the above I am using `**` as the exponentiation operator, as that is what it does in Chapel syntax). I recommend reading up on IEEE floating point formats (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format ) for background information in this area. You might care about this if you were using an RNG to generate test inputs to an algorithm operating on `real(64)` values. In that event you might wish for even the very small values to be generated. Note though that constructing an RNG that can generate all `real(64)` values in a non-uniform manner is not so hard (e.g. just by copying the bits from a `uint` into a `real`).

Regarding the other part of your question:

I did some basic statistical testing with the generation of random integers in a particular range with TestU01 and I'd be confident in its use with Monte Carlo calculations. However I am not an expert in this area and as a result I put that warning in the documentation. The below information from the documentation describes the testing that I did:

> We have tested this implementation with TestU01 (available at
>   http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/testu01/tu01.html ).  We measured our
>   implementation with TestU01 1.2.3 and the Crush suite, which consists
>   of 144 statistical tests. The results were:
>
> - no failures for generating uniform reals
> - 1 failure for generating 32-bit values (which is also true for the    reference version of PCG with the same configuration)
> - 0 failures for generating 64-bit values (which we provided to TestU01 as 2
>     different 32-bit values since it only accepts 32 bits at a time)
> - 0 failures for generating bounded integers (which we provided to TestU01 by requesting values in `[0..,2**31+2**30+1)` until we had two values < 2**31, removing the top 0 bit, and then combining the top 16 bits into the value provided to TestU01).

Comment: (Thanks very much for detailed answer, it's nice to hear that usual MC applications will be OK. I will read the linked pages and ask more questions if necessary.)